# Generic mapping in Automapper

Tags: c#, wcf, automapper, dto

Im trying to use automapper to convert Data Contracts to Client objects and vice versa.to reduce the lines of code and to make it simpler I want to create mapping dynamically.
Lets say I’m calling 5 different services and each service will return same object like Employee but data will be different(If I need employee info from Microsoft I will call Microsoft service or if I want IBM employee details I will call IBM service so on).

My object is something like below..

```
Public class Employee
{
Public string Id{get;set;}
Public string Division{get;set;}
Public PersonDetails person{get;set;}
}
Public class PersonDetails
{
Public string Name{get;set;}
Public string Email{get;set;}
Public string contact{get;set;}
}
```

Using Automapper I can write something below..

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Service1. PersonDetails, PersonDetails >();
   Mapper.CreateMap<Service1.Employee, Employee>()
        .ForMember(DEST=>DEST. PersonDetails,M=>M.MapFrom(Q=>Q. PersonDetails));
   Mapper.CreateMap<Service2. PersonDetails, PersonDetails >();
   Mapper.CreateMap<Service2.Employee, Employee>()
         .ForMember(DEST=>DEST.PersonDetails,M=>M.MapFrom(Q=>Q. PersonDetails));
```

ButI have to write same similar logic 5 times since i'm calling 5 different services.

Is there any way I can do this dynamically meaning i want to tell Automapper about source at runtime..

Please advise!!!

Comment: Are the services the same (not merely alike)? If that's the case, you should be able to use the exact same `DataContract` classes for all of them. On the other hand, if they're only merely alike, I don't see how Automapper would help you resolve the differences automatically.

Comment: @JeroenMostert services are different so each datacontract will come from different namespace.I'm thinking dynamic automapper may solve the issue but not sure how accurate it is..

Comment: What I mean is -- are the services *structurally* different (that is, are their requests completely different) or are they the same except for their endpoint addresses and the auto-generated namespaces? Because in your example above, there are no apparent differences.

Comment: Oh..they are same except endpoint address and auto generated namespaces..

Comment: In that case, you can add the service reference once and use the same classes for all the services. When creating a service instance, you can simply specify a new endpoint in the constructor.

Comment: Oh i see what u r saying..I think i misunderstood u r comment earlier("are the services structurally different")..those services have several other methods so  i guess that makes services structurally different so i can not add just single service reference(all need to be referenced)..

Answer (score 0):

looks like you should be able to map from an interface instead of the service itself.

```
public interface IEmployeeServiceResponce
{
    Employee {get;}
    PersonDetails{get;}
}
```

then have each service implement that interface.

This [articular](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping/) may articulate my suggestion a little more

if the return is not identical to the interface then I would recommend implementing the Adapter Patter to uniform them.

Comment: :Thank you for the reply..what u mean by "then have each service implement that interface.". how can we make change service implementation in case service is external..Could you little elaborate about the Adapter pattern that u r talking..